# What's the default v7 compat theme for AlertDialog

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

In my app I use the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as the base for my apps.
When I create a `AlertDialog` I'm using creating it without a specific theme.
Now I like to update some colors in the dialog, but I not know what's the theme that I need to use as a parent for the `AlertDialog`.
I have tried `Theme.Holo.Dialog` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` but aren't.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Comment: Isn't. If I force this theme for dialogs the Dialog is shown like in Gingerbread, but I'm in Lollipop

Answer (score 0):

I auto answer the question...

This si the default Dialog theme for v7 compat light theme (it needs to update the Dialog width (I don't know for what reason).

@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major
    @android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor

Answer (score 0):

the support library (sadly) doesn't have dialogs themes, at least not yet.

However, there are some third party libraries that allow you to have material design dialogs, such as [**AlertDailogPro**](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro/)

Answer (score 0):

With the new `AppCompat v22.1` you can use the new  [android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html).

Just use a code like this (of course in your case you have to use a custom layout to have the progress bar)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle("Dialog");
            builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.show();
```

And use a style like this:

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>
    </style>
```